# How to add multiple lines in tab strip of sap UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add new or second line in tab-strip.
Once the space is exhausted in first line ,I want another line to display tabs.
Can I get a sample code?
Note : Tabs are generated dynamically on click of button.

Comment: The IconTabBar was designed to support a single row for a reason. Do you really want to have a second line? Is there perhaps another way with other controls that you can achieve your goal?

Comment: Among UI/UX designers, having more than one row of tabs _"are confusing and intimidating, particularly to new users. These users find it difficult to locate the desired tab. In addition, screen real estate is compromised, and the repositioning of the tabs to the front row causes tremendous confusion and complexity"_ (quoted from http://classicsys.com/free-stuff-2/articles/usability-research-and-testing/leveraging-ui-design-with-agile-development/ If you really need that many tabs, you may try and use the `sap.suite.ui.commons.VerticalNavigationBar` control.

Comment: the Vertical Navigation Bar was useful,but i instead tried making height : initial in css and it worked.

Comment: thanks for your time
just one more question,if I have requirements of opening many(10-15) tabs at a same time, what would be preferable to use?

Answer (score 1):

The sap.m.IconTabBar only supports a single row of IconTabBarFilters and uses horizontal scroll when there is not room to display them all in one line.

In order to achieve your goal you need to define several IconTabBars and determine the number of IconTabBarFilters you want in each row. Once a IconTabBar is "full", add the next IconTabFilter to the next row's IconTabBar (and make it visible).

Comment: Thanks for your time.
i tried making height initial in css and it worked.

Comment: just one more question,if I have requirements of opening many(10-15) tabs at a same time, what would be preferable to use?

Comment: @user3312581 not sure what you mean with opening many tabs at the same time. Could you explain a bit more? I expect that tabs may not be the best user pattern for this and a collapsible type of control may be better

Comment: the requirement states that I use menu-events to open tabs on canvas area,on click of each menu item I need to open tabs,(which can be multiple and enormous in amount). Also ,if there is better alternative to tabs, please do reply

Comment: @user3312581 think you need to provide a quick sketch image of what your trying to achive. Even more confused now :)

Comment: refer the plug-in example Sir [plug-in](http://zozoui.com/tabs/dynamically/#themes)
I need to add dynamic tabs like the example and tabs may be many in number.